# How do I get all articles from the database?

Tags: 8, nodes

i am new on Drupal 8 ,in my case i want to get all articles from database filtered by name i have done dome code but it doesn't work for me can anyone help me please ?

```
public function getArticles(){
    $database = \Drupal::database();
    $query = $database->select('node', 'nd','article');
    return $query;
  }
```

update :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;


class ServiceValues{

 
  public function getArticles(){
    $storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node');
    $my_entity_ids = $storage->getQuery()
      ->condition('type', 'article')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->execute();
    $my_entities = $storage->loadMultiple($my_entity_ids);
    return $my_entities;
  }
}
```